# Light ticking sound on acceleration otherwise don't hear it not loud oil change done about 2 mos. Ago no lights temp gauge fine

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, focus

2003 ford focus. Rough idle rattles things inside vehicle . No acceleration issue or stalling. Just noticed a ticking sound when I start going only hear it when window down so not loud.

Comment: Can you get a video with sound? A rough idle can be caused by dozens of things, and the clicking might help narrow it down.